# SourceTree can't push to or pull from BitBucket Mercurial Repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Mercurial repository on BitBucket, and I use SourceTree to keep it synced with my local repository. When I want to make a new branch, what I usually do is create the branch on BitBucket and then open SourceTree and pull the latest changes, and then I update my working repository to the new branch. Then, when the changes are complete I merge the branch into default and push the changes back to BitBucket.

Lately, when I make a new branch on BitBucket and click pull in SourceTree it says there are no changes to be pulled. If I make changes in my local repository and try to push them it says there are no changes to be pushed.

However, if I use the command line interface to pull/push the changes it works correctly. I used this process 5+ times for other branches, and it just now stopped working, as if SourceTree is no longer connected to my BitBucket repository. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I had to do was update to the most up-to-date version of SourceTree.

Edit: I updated from version 2.6.10 to version 3.0.12.

Comment: If you can specify which version #s did and did not work, that may help future readers...